# Coldfusion cflocation strange behavior

Tags: coldfusion, cflocation

I am storing a google review URL in my database as:

```
https://www.google.com/search?CFID=ac59cfdf-bbad-4017-9759-e88054f3f242&CFTOKEN=0&q=njcomputerrepair%2Bbrick%2Bnj&oq=njcomp&aqs=chrome.1.69i60j69i59j69i60j69i57j0l2.2762j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#lrd=0x89c18348735c2907:0x59aa614832a36b22,3,
```

And then in my application I set that URL to a variable and I redirect the user to that URL using cflocation.

```
<cfquery name="geturl" datasource="#datasource#">
select (residential_ReviewURL) as redirectURL
from subscribers
</cfquery>

<!--- Redirect to main html redirect page --->
<cfoutput>
<cflocation url="#getURL.redirectURL#">
</cfoutput>
```

However the URL gets changed at some point because I think that Coldfusion doesn't like the characters in the URL and it replaces them with % or removes them. Therefore when the user hits the google page, the page doesn't process as it should.

Here is how the URL looks after the redirect:

```
https://www.google.com/search?CFID=ac59cfdf-bbad-4017-9759-e88054f3f242&CFTOKEN=0&CFID=ac59cfdf-bbad-4017-9759-e88054f3f242&CFTOKEN=0&q=njcomputerrepair%2Bbrick%2Bnj&oq=njcomp&aqs=chrome.1.69i60j69i59j69i60j69i57j0l2.2762j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#lrd%3D0x89c18348735c2907%3A0x59aa614832a36b22%2C3%2C
```

How can I stop ColdFusion from changing the URL and keep id exactly as how it is stored in the database?

## UPDATE

So I found that URLdecode will preserve the string. Here is what I have.

```
#urlDecode(getURL.redirectURL)#
```

The output is as follows

https://www.google.com/search?CFID=ac59cfdf-bbad-4017-9759-e88054f3f242&CFTOKEN=0&q=njcomputerrepair+brick+nj&oq=njcomp&aqs=chrome.1.69i60j69i59j69i60j69i57j0l2.2762j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#lrd=0x89c18348735c2907:0x59aa614832a36b22,3,

Why is it adding CFID and CFTOKEN to the URL though? I have it turned off in my Application.CFM:

```
<cfapplication name="yaya" 
    clientmanagement="no" 
    sessionmanagement="no" 
    setclientcookies="no" 
    setdomaincookies="no"
    sessiontimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(0,2,0,0)#" 
    applicationtimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(1,0,0,0)#"
      >
```

Comment: regarding the cfid and cftoken, have you tried adding addToken="no" to the cflocation?

Comment: Yes I have, but it doesn't seem to matter. But also, jsut outputting the URL to the screen shows the CFID and CFTOKEN in there.

Comment: @luke is correct, you have to specify `addToken="no"` to the cflocation tag in order for it to NOT append that to the URL.  If it is still in the URL after doing that then check your database contents `getURL.redirectURL` for it in there.

Comment: Even if I just output the URL to the screen, it shows the CFID and CFTOKEN, so that eliminates the cflocation aspect. I have confirmed that it is being stored in my DB without those tokens as well. Another thing I noticed is that if I pass the URL from the database in a URL variable, it adds it to that as well.

Comment: The url you are displaying in your question has a cfid and cftoken.

Comment: What happens if you remove the line `sessiontimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(0,2,0,0)#"` from your Application.cfm file? It should not be required since you have specified to not use session management.  This is also assuming that you have enabled "per application settings" in your ColdFusion administrator.

Comment: @DanBracuk - Yes you're right, been staring at this screen too long and totally missed that. Thanks. All is good.

Comment: You should write up your solution so that others can see how this was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**To help others coming here:**

`cflocation` have a parameter `addToken` which needs to set to `no` if we do not want to add `CFID` and `CFTOKEN` to the generated URL.

Adobe CFML reference: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-j-l/cflocation.html